# Different day formatting while using NSDateFormatter on OS X Mavericks and Yosemite

Tags: osx-mavericks, nsdateformatter, osx-yosemite

Given following program:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        f.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
        f.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
        f.calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
        f.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
        f.locale   = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ru"];

        NSDate *feb_01_2012 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1328054400];

        NSLog(@"%@", [f stringFromDate:feb_01_2012]);
    }
}
```

When compiled on OS X Yosemite produces following output:

```
2014-12-08 22:31:49.109 Untitled[14149:1398844] 1 февр. 2012 г.
```

However when compiled on OS X Mavericks it yields slightly different output (notice zero padding in day):

```
2014-12-08 22:27:01.890 formatter[54709:507] 01 февр. 2012 г.
```

Any ideas why this might happen? Bug only shows up for `ru` locale :-\

**UPDATE:** Found a way to get same amount of zeroes on both machines. Using `+dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale:` gives expected result:

```
NSLocale *l = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ru"];
f.locale = l;
f.dateFormat = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"yMMMd"
                                               options:0
                                                locale:l];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe different medium date format settings?

[image]

Comment: Nope. The same preferences on both machines.

Comment: Found a solution but not explanation why this happens, check out update.

Comment: This shouldn't affect it anyways because Roman explicitly sets locale for the formatter and he doesn't use `currentLocale`. So the locales he has on the machines shouldn't make any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to specify Russian locale more strictly. For example as `[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ru_RU"];`. I can suppose locale with identifier `ru` defaults to different locales on different OS X version. Though it's still weird...

And just to remind you can see the list of all locales available using `[NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers]`.

Comment: Tried with this identifier with no luck